# didreceiveremotenotification not getting called when app is forcequit

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I need to push data to server when my app is quit based on the notification.

But `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called when app is forcequit/terminated.

It's working fine in foreground/background mode.

Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: are you using this method - "- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:" just confirm?

Comment: If you check the console logs, you will see iOS print a log message that it is not waking up your app.  In other words, it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: Nothing you can do about that unfortunately.